# Using array in the columnDefinition for ENUM in Symfony

Tags: enums, annotations, doctrine, symfony4

When I use the columnDefinition in Symfony to define an ENUM column I need to write the possible values as pain text:

```
columnDefinition="ENUM('red', 'blue', 'green')"
```

Because this can cause errors in later stages I want to be able to put an array there:

```
columnDefinition="ENUM(static::COLORS)"
```

How can I solve this?

Answer (score 1):

You can create a Enum as a type and use it

```
<?php
namespace App\DBAL;



use Doctrine\DBAL\Types\Type;
use Doctrine\DBAL\Platforms\AbstractPlatform;

class EnumColorsType extends Type
{

    const ENUM_COLORS = 'enum_colors';
    const COLOR_RED = 'red';
    const COLOR_BLUE = 'blue';
    const COLOR_GREEN= 'green';

    publkic static $AVAILBLE_COLORS = ['blue','red','green']; 

    public function getSQLDeclaration(array $fieldDeclaration, AbstractPlatform $platform)
    {

        return sprintf("ENUM(%s)",implode(',', static::$AVAILBLE_COLORS));
    }

    public function convertToPHPValue($value, AbstractPlatform $platform)
    {
        return $value;
    }

    public function convertToDatabaseValue($value, AbstractPlatform $platform)
    {
        if (!in_array($value, static::$AVAILBLE_COLORS)) {
            throw new \InvalidArgumentException("Invalid Colors");
        }
        return $value;
    }

    public function getName()
    {
        return self::ENUM_COLORS;
    }


    public function requiresSQLCommentHint(AbstractPlatform $platform)
    {
        return true;
    }
}
```

Then use it

```
<?php
...
/** 
 * @ORM\Entity
 */
class YourEntity
{
    /** 
     * @Column(type="enum_colors") 
     */
    private $color;
}
```

Comment: Good answer! But how can I use this for more than one field? Is there an option to make this dynamic? I mean when I have in one Entity 3 enums, then I need to create 3 classes like the EnumColorsType. Is there a better way to create one class and handle all enum columns as parameters?

Comment: You are welcome ,You can use it like other types (string ,interger..)
there is no problem you can have 3 fields with the same type on the same entity

Comment: Hi @iraouf 10x. I mean is there a way to make a global class EnumType and somehow with a parameter to pass the name of the column and the possible values. If I have 10 Enums I don't want to write 10 classes for enums.